# Does "smaller clothes hangers for petite women" really pass the novel requirement?

Tags: patentability, novelty, novel

According to this article https://www.upcounsel.com/non-obvious

`"If your idea is to make clothes hangers in smaller sizes for petite women's clothing, it's possible that your invention is novel, but simply making clothing hangers in a smaller size would still be quite obvious to people who already make hangers."`

What makes it novel, if you agree with the article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rare that making something bigger or smaller is not deemed to be obvious.

If some “invention” is need to do miniaturization or if only one portion has a size change resulting in different behavior it might be non-obvious. A smaller hanger for a smaller garment might be novel but wouldn’t be non-obvious.

The case that determined this, [In re Rose](https://casetext.com/case/application-of-rose-2) had to do with smaller bundles of wood with the wood sorted by size.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a lawyer. That said, to me novel means never been done before. So if all hangers are approximately the same size and someone decides to make a smaller hanger for petite clothing and that was the first one ever, it would be novel. In reality, there actually are hangers made over a range of sizes so the example doesn't seem novel. To make sense you have to ignore that.